# Как выглядит content_type в версии 3.х aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Как выглядит content_type в версии 3.х aiogram для TEXT. Нашел один ответ с Content, но он не помог.
Сейчас он у меня эта строчка кода выглядит так:
`@dp.message(content_type=ContentType.TEXT)`
Но говорит, что такой формат использовался в aiogram 2.x.

Comment: в заголовке должно быть краткое описание проблемы, а не твоя минибиография

Comment: Извините, я впервые в stack overflow. Возьму на заметку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В aiogram 3.x можно использовать магический фильтр `F`.

```py
from aiogram import Dispatcher, F
from aiogram.types import ContentType

dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(F.content_type == ContentType.TEXT)
```

[Магический фильтр F](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html) хранит в себе `message`. Таким образом с ним можно работать как с условием на сообщение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало